# AWS RDS same file_guids

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, aws

Getting this error on AWS RDS with MS SQL

> Database XXX cannot be restored because there is already an existing
>   database with the same file_guids on the instance.

I've imported from S3 once, it worked. Deleted the database and tried to import a more recent version FULL DB and it broke.

I've created a new instance also but still get the error. I can import other DBs from S3 fine.

Anyone have any ideas that can help?

Comment: I deleted all the instances and created a new one and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue last week.
The issue was resolved on RDS.

It is possible to restore files with similar guids.

See tests and results in the attached pictures.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

yes you need to extract the BACPAC file

Comment: Can you expand on your answer? Please provide an explanation as to why you think this will resolve the problem that the OP is having.